# Samsung galaxy mobile Email style query

Tags: android, css, email, mobile, html-email

I have done some searching and found that the default app does not support media query.. but my boss insist that it can be done somehow.

Anyone have pointers on where to look for solutions?

mostly just display widths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The native client does support media queries ([see here](https://litmus.com/help/email-clients/media-query-support/)) but there are some restrictions ([see here](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/how_android_is_strangling_responsive_design)).

The major restriction is that you cannot use TD stacking in most new android devices, but instead need to use Table stacking.

It has been found also that using TH tag instead of TD can alleviate this issue as well. Using "display:block; width:100%" on media queries targeting these TH still work despite not working on TDs.

My best advice is to test your emails on something like Email on Acid or Litmus and see what works best for you.

Comment: my question was for the samsung galaxy which is *not* native app.

Comment: Then if not using a native email client then no, media queries are not supported. You will need to build email for gmail client and use media queries and Mso conditionals to make work on desktop.